# SSRS 2008 R2 - Subscribe facility

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting-services, bids

Which version of SSRS 2008 do you need to have before users can subscribe to reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Standard and higher allows users to subscribe to reports. Perhaps you're thinking about Data Driven Subscriptions? That requires Enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need Standard Edition for standard subscriptions.  However if you want to utilise data-driven subscriptions, you will need Datacenter or Enterprise editions.

Check out http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/compare.aspx for comparison table (SSRS functionality is third from the bottom).